# Are admissible topological rings compactly generated?

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra, topological-groups, topological-rings

Suppose $R$ is a (commutative unital) topological ring which is admissible in the sense of [Stacks 07E8](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07E8): it is complete, Hausdorff, admits a fundamental system of neighborhoods of zero consisting of ideals, and admits an open ideal $I$ such that every neighborhood of 0 contains $I^n$ for some $n$. Is $R$ necessarily compactly generated as a topological space? What if we require $R$ to be Noetherian?

If $R$ is first-countable, e.g. if $R$ is adic (again in the sense of Stacks 07E8), the answer is yes: every first-countable space is compactly generated. However, I don't see any further cases.

I ask this in the hope that it is nicer to consider formal schemes to have a structure sheaf of condensed rings, rather than topological rings.

Comment: hi Curious, nice question! just to make sure I'm understanding – would an example of such a ring be $k[[x]]$ for a field $k$?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Yes, this is such a ring (in the (x)-adic topology)!